# NSPopover switch view

Tags: macos, nsviewcontroller, nspopover

I have a popover menulet and it's contentViewController is some NSViewController. Everything fine here. The problem that I have is that I really don't understand how to change the View. I wanna load another view, and this is what I tried:

```
popover = [[NextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:[popover view]];
```

And this works, new view is shown - but if I click on any button on that view I get error: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Why am I getting this error? Why this new view is not responding?

Please help me understand what I need to do, how to change the view on **NSPopover**?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve my problem, It turn out to be quite easy:

```
[self.view setSubviews:[NSArray array]]; //remove all previous subviews
[self.view addSubview:[popover view]];
```